# How to integrate SecuGen Fingerprint Scanner through USB into an Android Application

Tags: android, android-studio, fingerprint, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api

I want to build an android application which requires to use fingerprint scanning. I'm using an external SecuGen fingerprint scanner (SecuGen Hamster Pro 20) for this. How to integrate this to my android app.The SDK for  SecuGen fingerprint scanning is available. How to start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SDK provided to you, with SecuGen Hamster Pro 20, a "Programming manual" is given, which consist of all the steps to integrate scanner with your android app. This SDK also contains Demo android project which will help you to code and sample apk is also provided. And a set of "Java Doc" files is also given for help. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me.