how to access secugen hamster 20 pro , capture fingerprint image in android application
I am creating an Android application in which I want to access the thumb impression of the user. I want to integrate the Secugen Hamster 20 Pro device into my Android application for thumb scanning.

Ask the manufacturer if they have an Android SDK for their hardware.

Please refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520612/how-to-integrate-secugen-fingerprint-scanner-through-usb-into-an-android-applica

In the SDK provided to you, with SecuGen Hamster Pro 20, a "Programming manual" is given, which consist of all the steps to integrate scanner with your android app. This SDK also contains Demo android project which will help you to code and sample apk is also provided. And a set of "Java Doc" files is also given for help. Hope this will help you.
